# Youtube data api returns accessNotConfigured when inserting liveCuepoints

Tags: youtube-api

**What I want to achieve**

I want to insert cuepoints into a livestream on youtube.
You can manage them logged in at (youtube.com/my_live_events).
Documentation is found here:
http://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveCuepoints/insert

What I do to achieve this:

**1 Authenticated**

I added my server to the api console and created api keys and all.
This worked, I got by the "unauthenticated error"

**2 Refreshed the access token**

With the refresh token. (I do it every time, the php code just in case):

```
$account = gauth_account_load(1,false);
if ($account['is_authenticated']) {
  $json = json_decode($account['access_token']);
  $access_token = $json->access_token;
  $client = gauth_client_get(1,FALSE);
  if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $client->refreshToken($json->refresh_token);
    $account['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    $json = json_decode($account['access_token']);
    $access_token = $json->access_token;
    gauth_account_save($account);
  }
}
```

This works fine to not get the "Invalid Credentials" error when the token has timed out.

**3 Construct the URI**

As documented in link above, this is the URL to use:
{https://}www.googleapis.com/youtube/partner/v1/liveCuepoints?channelId=UC%&key=AI%

*I added curly brackets because had only permission to add 1 real link*

Where 
UC% is my channel ID (found in http://www.youtube.com/account_advanced) and AI% is my server API KEY. (from the api console)

The content in the POST request is the following json

```
{
"id":"cqOZjdltLMk",
"broadcastId":"cqOZjdltLMk",
"kind":"youtubePartner#liveCuepoint",
"settings":
{
"offsetTimeMs":0,
"cueType":"ad",
"durationSecs":10
}
}
```

Now I'm not sure about the id and broadcastId (Should this be the unique movie/livestream id) ? That's what I added in there.

**4 The result**

This is what I get from the request:
code : 403

```
{
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
    "message": "Access Not Configured"
}
```

Google searches for "accessNotConfigured" resulted in a lot of different api stuff, but not one related to the cuepoints.

**Help**

What am I doing wrong?
Helpful links are very welcome!

Comment: There was a problem with the whitelisting (google told us).
So they fixed things and now wee can see the "youtube content ID API".
The error we get now is 
> "code": 400,   "message": "Required"

But I guess that's another problem to which the solution is findable.
On that one now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LiveCuepoint is actually in a different API. To be able to use cuePoint, you have to be use YouTube partner and also have access to Content ID API.

Comment: I can't find both "youtube partner" or "content id api" you mentioned  in the api console... Where do I look for the docs on these?

Comment: It means you don't have access. Only YouTube partners have access to that.

Comment: I'll contact our yt contact and post more here later... thanks.

Comment: After contact with google, they are now debugging this.
It seems the problem is me not getting these api accesses in to my account.

Comment: After verified my google developer account in youtube, the youtube partner api still does not show up on the Google Console. @FrederikWouters have you got it?

Comment: No, you need Youtube Content ID API and Youtube Data API v3